# How to form some tag questions?

Tags: negation, tag-questions, prefixes

We always use a positive tag question after a negative sentence:

> You shouldn't take this medicine, should you?

We use a negative tag question after a positive sentence:

> She must leave early, mustn't she?

But when there is a negating prefix on the adjective (impatient vs. patient) after the verb "to be", then the sentence is negative in meaning. Does this mean the tag should be positive?

Which is correct, A or B?

> A: I am impatient, am I?
>
> B: I am impatient, aren't I?
>
> A: The class was dismissed, was it?
>
> B: The class was dismissed, wasn't it?

Comment: What do you call a prefix in your question? You can find how to build a "tag question" in lots of places on the web: [here](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-questions-tag.htm) or [here](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/tagquestions.html) or [here](http://www.eslbase.com/grammar/tag-questions) and lots and lots more. "The class was dismissed,wasn't it?" and "I am impatient,aren't I?" are the correct sentences. What you say in your first paragraph is correct.

Comment: @Laure by prefix I think it's meant *im* or *dis*, as in impatient or dismissed.

Comment: Thanks Laure,I know the basic structure.But can you give me a cogent explanations for your answer?

Comment: I gave you three links that explains it all. The fact you use "impatient" or "patient", or whatever adjective does not change anything. The whole structure lies on a verb/auxiliary - positive/negative relationship.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone. Well, that needed a lot of guessing !Well done.

Comment: @Laure,I can understand what you said.Well,I have an exam tomorrow and my teacher gave me these answers(am I?was it?)

Comment: You'll be fine for your exam and just forget about the meaning of the adjective. I hadn't understood your question at first until  BobStein-VisiBone rectified it. Plenty of exercises on the web if you want to train: [here](http://www.english-zone.com/grammar/tags01.html) [here](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/exercises/questions/question_tags3.htm]and [here](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-exercise-tag-questions.php#.UxeDe9up2sE). By the way welcome to ELL! If you like English, you'll come back.

Comment: The only case that could be found tricky would be when the subject of the statement is a negative indefinite pronoun such has "Nothing's impossible, is it?" or "No one's coming, are they", and you have to remember that it is a negative statement.

Comment: Thanks again Laure,you helped me so much and it was very kind from you.I get full mark in my exam,it was very easy and simple.It was very helpful from ELL,and I will keep in touch

Answer (score 2):

The negative prefix on the adjective does not matter, the tag question is determined solely by whether the verb is negative or positive.  The correct usage would be "I am impatient, aren't I?" There are occasions for when you could use a positive-positive tag, but it's not really a question (the "up" inflection isn't there). It's used to confirm another person's statement often expressing mocking, doubt, wonder, anger, etc.

**Example**

Person A:  I was sick yesterday and spent the entire day in bed.

Person B:  You were sick, were you? Then how come I saw you jogging in the park?

Person A:  My wife is going to have a baby.

Person B:  She is, is she? Congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

Both variations are possible but they arise in different contexts and have different meanings.

> I am impatient, am I?

Someone has accused the speaker of being impatient. For example in the kitchen, ruining the roux sauce by adding the milk too quickly. The speaker is irritated at the accusation, and retorts in a sarcastic tone; you can almost hear the next utterance: "I'll show you what impatience is!" and stomping off in a sulk.

> I am impatient, aren't I?

This is more likely said with a self-deprecating smile, or said ironically. For example, a husband waiting for his wife to get ready to leave, going out to start the car while she's still putting on her make-up (stereotype alert!). He says to her as she finally gets in the car...

Comment: I suppose OP uses "tag question" in the sense used in ESL books, i.e. a sentence that is used to confirm or check information or ask for agreement. That does not include your first example, which would have a different punctuation anyway.

Comment: @Laure I have to disagree on both counts. My first example does seek confirmation (albeit in a slightly aggressive/rhetorical way), and I see nothing untoward with my punctuation.

Comment: Then you probably missed out a word and meant "I am impatient, am I ***not**? if not it is not a "tag question" as such.

Comment: Similarly, I'd say _The class was dismissed, wasn't it?_ when I suspected the class was dismissed. It's not really a question per se, I'm just summarizing my conclusion. The only answer I would expect is, "Yes, it was." As for, _The class was dismissed, was it?_, I read that with a heavy emphasis on the word _dismissed_, and an accusatory tone overall. It sounds like something an attorney would say in a courtroom when he's about to make an "Aha!" point.

Comment: @Laure No, I wrote what I intended and it remains a tag question despite your insistence otherwise. See "balanced vs unbalanced" tags in the wiki entry at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question

Answer (score -1):

No, that is a hypercorrection. You only follow "is/is not", do not form a tag question based on negative prefix.

**Correct**: I am impatient, am I not?

**Correct**: I am not patient, am I?

Comment: "Aren't I?" but "**am I**?"